# Querying a for table not defined in models Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this table in my database (using Posgresql and Sqlalchemy) called "participants".
In my models.py I want to access the participant's records. Since participants is not in my models.py and resides as a table in my db, when I do `query = db.session.query('participants').order_by('name').all()` I get an error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "participants" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT participants ORDER BY name
           ^
```

What can I do to retrieve this information?

Comment: Would sending raw sql queries, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17987782/2003420), be acceptable ?

Comment: I tried it out, I think it's okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comment on the original post, did something like:

`query = db.engine.execute('select * from participants order by name')`
This doesn't give it in the same format as the query so I could use it for what I needed (a dictionary output, and a format for web), so I did:

```
partner_list = []
for record in query:
    record_dict = dict(record)
    partner_list.append(record_dict)
```