# Sqlalchemy, raw query and parameters

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to perform raw sql query using sqlalchemy and wondering what is a 'proper' way to do it.

My query looks as follows (for now):

```
db.my_session.execute(
    """UPDATE client SET musicVol = {}, messageVol = {}""".format(
    music_volume, message_volume))
```

What I don't like is string formatting and lack of any parameter handling (hello to quotation marks in music_volume :-D).

I tried to follow this answer:

[How to execute raw SQL in SQLAlchemy-flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-sqlalchemy-flask-app#answer-18808942)

And after applying what I read, my snippet looks as follows:

```
db.my_session.execute(
    "UPDATE client SET musicVol = :mv , messageVol = :ml", mv=music_volume, ml=message_volume)
```

However I am getting error that mv and ml is not recognized parameter.

If I change my snippet into this, it works:

```
db.my_session.execute(
    "UPDATE client SET musicVol = :mv , messageVol = :ml", {mv: music_volume, ml: message_volume})
```

Lastly my_session is initiated like that in a file called db.py:

```
engi = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mysql://{user}:{passwd}@{host}/{db}'.format(
        host=settings.HOST,
        user=settings.USER,
        passwd=settings.PASS,
        db=settings.DB_NAME), execution_options={
        'autocommit': True,
    })

my_session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engi), scopefunc=os.getpid)
sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session.configure(my_session, autocommit=True)
```

What I would like to know is why answer linked above and this part of documentation:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#using-text

Are showing slightly different solution to what actually is working for me.

Also if my approach is one to go.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Both `mv` and `ml` will not be recognized, since you haven't defined them as variables.

The second argument of `execute` statement is a dictionary, and all the elements of your plain query `"UPDATE client SET musicVol = :mv , messageVol = :ml"` escaped with a colon are being searched for in this dictionary's keys. The `execute` method did not found a key `'mv'` nor `'ml'` in this dictionary, therefore an error is raised.

This is the correct version:

```py
db.my_session.execute(
    "UPDATE client SET musicVol = :mv, messageVol = :ml",
    {'mv': music_volume, 'ml': message_volume}
)
```

Comment: While your comment is helpful there is one thing that you did not answered. If you follow the link I have added to the question, there is a snippet of code like that:

# recommended
cmd = 'select * from Employees where EmployeeGroup == :group'
employeeGroup = 'Staff'
employees = connection.execute(text(cmd), group = employeeGroup)

And it works without using dictionary. Why is that?

Comment: It's because you're using `execute(type_str)` and example shows the usage of `execute(type_text)`. You can have the same result as in example by using `from sqlalchemy.sql import text` and `cmd = text('select * from Employees where EmployeeGroup == :group')` and finally `connection.execute(text(cmd), group=employeeGroup)`.

Comment: When working with SqlAlchemy core, use `text('UPDATE ...')` or parameters won't work

Comment: Can you use parameters to allow the user to apply filtering operations?

Comment: For example, if the user wants to filter by album creation date and/or by author, can I say something like "SELECT...WHERE :filter"?

Comment: Don't really know how this looks like in SQLAlchemy as I no longer have up to date experience with it, but since the first argument to `execute` is a plain Python string you can easily work with it. 

If you have an optional `query_filter` argument that can be `None` or e.g. `"type = 'new'"` you can easily add this optionally to the query. 

`query = "UPDATE client SET musicVol = :mv, messageVol = :ml"
if query_filter is not None: 
    query = f"{query} WHERE {query_filter}"
result = db.my_session.execute(query, {"mv": music_volume, "ml": message_volume})`