# Passing parameters not being recognized and throws SQL error when executing raw query (on SQL-Server database and Pymssql) with SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql, parameterized-query

I'm trying to execute simple raw SQL query, on SQL-Server db with SqlAlchemy (and Pymssql as provider).

Here is my first try (using `execute` method of connection and passing parameters in **kwargs way):

```
provider = DataProvider().engine
q = "select url from Crawler.CrawlSource where source=@source"
query = text(q)
result = provider.connect().execute(query, source ='mysource')
```

I passed the parameters in any way shown in tutorials (passing as kwargs and passing as dict) but neither of them worked and when `execute` method is called an exception is thrown that says **`'Must declare the scalar variable' @source`** as if no parameter is passed to `execute` method, it seems ORM (or maybe data provider (pymssql in this case) ) doesn't recognize parameters passed to `execute` method and passes only query (without parameters) to db engine (which causes the exception).

I guess there might be some issue with MSSQL-Server provider (Pymssql) since SQL-Server is not first class citizen in SqlAlchemy and Python family, but have no direct clue what could causes this.

as I said above I also tried other ways as well

Here is my second try (using `execute` method of connection and passing parameters as dict):

```
provider = DataProvider().engine
q = "select url from Crawler.CrawlSource where source=@source"
query = text(q)
result = provider.connect().execute(query, {source :'mysource'})
```

My third try (using `execute` method of engine object and passing parameters in **kwargs way):

```
provider = DataProvider().engine
q = "select url from Crawler.CrawlSource where source=@source"
query = text(q)
result = provider.execute(query, source ='mysource')
```

My forth try (using `execute` method of engine object and passing parameters as dict):

```
provider = DataProvider().engine
q = "select url from Crawler.CrawlSource where source=@source"
query = text(q)
result = provider.execute(query, {source :'mysource'})
```

My fifth try (creating a session and using `execute` method of session and passing parameters as dict):

```
provider = DataProvider().engine
session = sessionmaker(bind=provider)()
q = "select url from Crawler.CrawlSource where source=@source"
query = text(q)
result = session.execute(query, {source :'mysource'})
```

My sixth try (creating a session and using `execute` method of session and passing parameters in **kwargs way):

```
provider = DataProvider().engine
session = sessionmaker(bind=provider)()
q = "select url from Crawler.CrawlSource where source=@source"
query = text(q)
result = session.execute(query,  source='mysource')
```

but as I mentioned earlier none of the effortsabove worked and all of them led to the same exception mentioned above

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try using `... where source = :source`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29208847/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson tried that, ':' not working for passing parameters in sql-server it works for Postgress I think

Comment: @GordThompson it aint duplicate. The post you sent is not for SQL-Server. If you had read the question correctly I also mentioned that I passed my parameters as a dictionary and didn't work as well. I guess there is some thing wrong with SQL-Server compatibility because it works for other databases when passing paramters as dict

Comment: No, `:` style (named) params work "natively" on cx_Oracle driver, for example, but SQLAlchemy `text()` converts named style to what ever your driver uses. In addition `Session.execute()` handles text queries as if wrapped with `text()` automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mssql+pymssql dialect appears to support the "pyformat" [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). This works for me:

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pymssql://@localhost:49242/myDb")

sql = "SELECT word FROM vocabulary WHERE language = %(lang)s"
params = {'lang': 'Greek'}
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(sql, params).fetchall()
    print(result)
    # [('γιορτή',), ('ηλεκτρονικός υπολογιστής',)]
```

We can also use the "named" paramstyle if we use a SQLAlchemy `text` object:

```python
sql = sa.sql.text("SELECT word FROM vocabulary WHERE language = :lang")
params = {'lang': 'Greek'}
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(sql, params).fetchall()
    print(result)
    # [('γιορτή',), ('ηλεκτρονικός υπολογιστής',)]
```

The `text` object allows us to consistently use the "named" paramstyle regardless of the native paramstyle supported by the DB-API layer (e.g., `%s` for pymssql, `?` for pyodbc).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second option worked for me!