# Adding data into SQL with python won't work

Tags: python, sql

I have a python script that should be able to write data into a made SQL table. I have these lines that should do it:

```py
#Connect to the database
testDBCon = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://SRVISCDB,58837/testDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')

#Choose what query to select a column from
query = "SELECT * FROM testDB.dbo.SuspensiaImageDetails;"

query = "INSERT INTO testDB.dbo.SuspensiaImageDetails (FileName, 
         FileSize, FilePath, Height, Width, Format, Mode, Frames)VALUES ("
query += line
query += ");"
```

The output that I get when I `print(query)` and I get this:

```
    INSERT INTO testDB.dbo.SuspensiaImageDetails (FileName, FileSize, 
    FilePath, Height, Width, Format, Mode, Frames)VALUES (,X01LA0295.JPG
                      ,9718                           ,.JPG                           
       ,400
       600                            ,JPEG                           ,RGB                            
    ,1                              ,);
```

A few issues I see is all the gaps in-between the values, as well as commas in-between the values. I have this line that puts a comma in-between the values but it puts it in the front and end of every value. However those may be an issue as well.

```
line += f",{str(value):<30} "
```

My question is how can I fix these lines to get the values I have into the SQL database table?

Comment: Well for starters, you need single quotes around your char/varchar values. You've also got too many commas.

Comment: So I need a sing quote around each value I want to add? I added that by doing `line += f",'{str(value):<30}' "` Wat else would I need to do to add it to the Table

Comment: don't build the sql query by concat-ing together from Python strings, the db library has tools to help you do this safely and to automatically quote the values when needed according to the db backend and column type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32333755/202168

Comment: After reading that i see that they use `UPDATE` i assume I would be using `INSERT` yet I am still confused on how the line would look

Comment: why do you use `<30`? it adds spaces to inserted strings. Simply use `f"'{value}'"` with `' '` inside `" "`. But it could be better to use special functions to create queries - like in some modules `execute("INSERT ... (?, ?, ?, ...)", data)` with `?` or `% as placeholders

Comment: Thank you that fixed the spacing however can you explain the `execute(query, data)` statement

Comment: [python - How to execute raw SQL in Flask-SQLAlchemy app - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-flask-sqlalchemy-app)

Comment: you define `query = """INSERT INTO testDB.dbo.SuspensiaImageDetails
(FileName, FileSize, FilePath, Height, Width, Format, Mode, Frames)
VALUES
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""` and `data = ("X01LA0295.JPG", 9718, ".JPG", 400, 600, "JPEG", "RGB", 1)` and later you use special function `execute(query, data)` to run this query with data

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @furas, the best way would be to use placeholders.
(%s for strings, %i for integers)

```python
import sqlalchemy

testDBCon = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://SRVISCDB,58837/testDB?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')

#Choose what query to select a column from
query1 = "SELECT * FROM testDB.dbo.SuspensiaImageDetails;"

query2 = "INSERT INTO testDB.dbo.SuspensiaImageDetails (FileName, 
         FileSize, FilePath, Height, Width, Format, Mode, Frames) VALUES (%s,%i,%s,%i,%i,%s,%s,%i)"

values = ('X01LA0295.JPG',9718,'.JPG',400,600,'JPEG','RGB',1) 

engine.execute(query2,values)
```

Happy Coding!