# SQLalchemy: iterate through raw SQL query in template

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

Have a code in function, which renders ResultProxy (as I understand), to template,  like this:

```
query = db_session.execute(serious_business_query) #raw sql
return render_template('result.html', query=query)
```

I want to iterate through it in my template, but see nothing. How can I iterate through ResultProxy object? Or what should I pass to template to simply iterate through it?

*Links to docs are OK, cant find what I need.*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/17987782/1307985
and when you fill in a list from the cursor then to pass it to the template.

I am guessing, but probably the jinja2 template does not know how to itterate over cursor or query like object so it have to be converted to a list object.