# How to use Records with Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My Flask app should execute some rather complicated sql queries, parse them and display results. Now I'm using SQLAlchemy (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17987782/6035986)), but I want to switch to [Records](https://github.com/kennethreitz/records), simple wrapper over SQLAlchemy (it has all I need out of the box). I haven't found any examples of integration Records into Flask.

Can you provide an example of simple Flask app with vanilla Records integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Records` handle the SQLAlchemy connection lifecycle, I don't think it is a good idea to really integrate them. You can share the config, passing the database URL to `records.Database`.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DATABASE_URL'] = 'postgres://...'
records_db = records.Database(app.config['DATABASE_URL'])
```

If you use `Flask-SQLAlchemy`, the config key is `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`.

Add the `records_db` to Flask context [`g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.g) to access it from any file with a Flask context, without messing with circular imports.

```
from flask import g
g.records = records_db
```