# Is there any way to execute sql script using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to execute an SQL script against a MSSQL server. In the script I have created table variable by selecting data from a table, then get the data from the variable. But it returns an array with no values.

SQL:

```
DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE
(
  ProductID int, 
  Revenue money
)

INSERT INTO @ProductTotals (ProductID, Revenue)
SELECT ProductID, SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity)
    FROM [Order Details]

SELECT * FROM @ProductTotals
```

Python:

```
data = connection_to_database.execute(sqlFile)  
for i in data:  
    print(i)
```

Comment: like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17987782/2758823 ?