# Cannot execute raw sql when using flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I want to specifically run this sql code in my flask app:

```
SELECT *, (upvotes - downvotes) * age / importance * -1 AS hotness FROM 'post' ORDER BY hotness DESC LIMIT 50
```

To do this I used flask-sqlalchemy like so:

```
    self.hotness = db.engine.execute(text("SELECT *, (upvotes - downvotes) * age / importance * -1 AS hotness FROM 'post' ORDER BY hotness DESC LIMIT 50").execution_options(autocommit=True))
    return self.hotness
```

As suggested on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-sqlalchemy-flask-app) question.

The problem is that the `self.hotness` variable always comes out as `None` even though all the other variables referenced in the sql code are not `None`, they are numbers.

I'm guessing that the problem is due to the actual sql code not being committed into the table used here, which is `post`.

How would I properly commit data made from raw sql using flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: When you say all the other variables have a value, you mean that for any given row, they all have a value? My guess is that at least one of them is possibly `NULL` for a row, which resulted in `None`, and since you're sorting by `hotness`, the `None`s are bubbling up to the top. You also don't have to commit a select statement. Commits are for inserts, updates, or deletes.

Comment: I have checked and seen that every single value inputted into the equation is an integer (which it should be). You mentioned that commits are for updates, so say I have a hotness value of `None` could I use an update command to update the value to an integer using the above equation? I think using the SELECT keyword was a mistake on my part.

Comment: Yes, you can use the update command. Just keep in mind that the SQL equivalent for Python's `None` is `NULL`, so in your WHERE clause, you want something like `WHERE hotness IS NULL`