# How can I order by A a-Z z- symbol

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to return: Aa-Zz-symbol (like: ",1,2,3,+,-)

```
query.order_by(sqlalchemy.asc(getattr(schema.Study, name)))
```

it returns: symbol-Aa-Zz

example:

study table:

```
| 16SYB  | 
| "test" |
| a      |
| z      |
```

i want to return:

```
a
z
"test"
16SYB
```

but my code return:

```
"test"
16SYB
a
z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can play with capital letters order using [collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html), e.g:

```
t=# with c(v) as (values('16SYB'),('"test"'),('a'),('z'),('A'))
select v from c order by v collate "en_US.utf8";
   v
--------
 16SYB
 a
 A
 "test"
 z
(5 rows)
```

vs:

```
t=# with c(v) as (values('16SYB'),('"test"'),('a'),('z'),('A'))
select v from c order by v collate "C";
   v
--------
 "test"
 16SYB
 A
 a
 z
(5 rows)
```

but in your case it's a little more complicated:

```
t=# with c(v) as (values('16SYB'),('"test"'),('a'),('z'),('A'))
select v from c order by case when v ~ '\d' then 9 when v ~ '"' then 8 else 0 end, v collate "en_US.utf8";
   v
--------
 a
 A
 z
 "test"
 16SYB
(5 rows)
```

of course you can play with this ordering rule yourself to expand or change it

**update**
My proposed method does not uses sqlalchemy methods. I suppose you would need to [use raw sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-sqlalchemy-flask-app) to implement it as I propose.

**update2**

As kindly proposed by Ilja Everilä, this should help:

```
col = getattr(schema.Study, name)
query.order_by(case([(col.op('~')(r'\d'), 9),
                     (col.op('~')('"'), 8)],
                    else_=0),
               col.collate('en_US.utf8'))
```

sorry my ignorance - I can't check this due to total absence of sqlalchemy knowledge

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes - I should have mentioned it. Hope updated version is more clear about my solution flaw. Thank you

Comment: my data comes from my database, I just give an example to describe my question: Aa-Zz-symbol (sorry for my english)

Comment: My feeling with most SQL frameworks is that they just don't support complex stuff, but +1 to you.

Comment: @IljaEverilä great! thank you. So you will post your answer then?

Comment: @IljaEverilä - yes, sure. Alas I can't check if it works :) but anyway - thank you!

Comment: @IljaEverilä to order it alphabetically you need to add `colname` after case - would you please? (if its not somehow implicitly of course)