# Update a SQL table with data from itself using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a short SQL script which "copies" selected columns from a SQL table from one id (`main_id=1`) to two other ids (`main_id=3` and `4`) of the same table.
There are also some other ids which are part of the primary key of the table.

The script works fine using a PostgreSQL DB.
However, i would like to replace this using SQLAlchemy ORM, but i don't know how to do this.

```sql
UPDATE "MyTable" AS T
SET "Varname_1" = Cell."Varname_1",
    "Varname_2" = Cell."Varname_2"
FROM "MyTable" AS Cell
WHERE T.id_A = Cell.id_A AND
      T.id_B = Cell.id_B AND
      Cell.main_id = 1 AND
      T.main_id IN (3, 4);
```

Can anyone help me to "translate" this?

Comment: Why don't you execute this query directly?

Comment: First, if i could do this in SQLAlchemy, i would be using SQLAlchemy for all database actions in my program, instead of a mix of SQLAlchemy and raw SQL. Second, portability: (as far as i know) the script above does not work for all SQL dialects. Before using Postgres i used a MS SQL server, for which i had to use a different script.

Comment: I meant [executing the raw SQL via SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808942/1026), and I don't think this SQL should differ a lot between dialects (looks like valid T-SQL to me), but see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you were having problems with, as I was able to do this by following the examples from [Multiple Table Updates](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#multiple-table-updates) and [Using Aliases and Subqueries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#using-aliases-and-subqueries) sections of the tutorial:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import alias
metadata = MetaData()

my_table = Table('MyTable', metadata,
    Column('id_A', Integer),
    Column('id_B', Integer),
    Column('main_id', Integer),
    Column('varname_1', String),
    Column('varname_2', String),
)
cell = my_table.alias("cell")
stmt = my_table.update(). \
    where(my_table.c.id_A == cell.c.id_A). \
    where(my_table.c.id_B == cell.c.id_B). \
    where(cell.c.main_id == 1). \
    where(my_table.c.main_id.in_([3, 4])). \
    values(varname_1=cell.c.varname_1,
           varname_2=cell.c.varname_2)
print(str(stmt))
print(stmt.compile().params)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. (My main problem are my very limited SQL skills... ;-) )

Comment: @boseki Glad to hear that! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.