# Flask-SQLAlchemy: How to change table structure?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have a table model in a flask application:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    pubDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

And I use `db.crate_all()` and `db.add()`/`db.session` to add some data to the above table, work well!

Then I want to update and add some properties of class Article:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    createDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    touchDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    publishDate = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    isVisible = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
    isDraft = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
```

After I update the class Article, I use `db.create_all()` again. When I run my flask application, I got following error message:

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: article.createDate
[SQL: SELECT article.id AS article_id, article.title AS article_title, article.body AS article_body, article."createDate" AS "article_createDate", article."touchDate" AS "article_touchDate", article."publishDate" AS "article_publishDate", article."isVisible" AS "article_isVisible", article."isDraft" AS "article_isDraft" 
FROM article 
WHERE article."isVisible" = 1]
```

Whenever I change the `db.Model` subclass, does the table in database sync automatically? What operation is needed after the properties of `db.Model` subclass change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an industrial-strength solution, [**Flask-Migrate**](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is an extension that handles SQLAlchemy database migrations for Flask applications using [**Alembic**](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/).

> Alembic is a database migration tool written by the author of [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). A migrations tool offers the following functionality:
>
> - Can emit ALTER statements to a database in order to change the structure of tables and other constructs
> - Provides a system whereby “migration scripts” may be constructed; each script indicates a particular series of steps that can “upgrade” a target database to a new version, and optionally a series of steps that can “downgrade” similarly, doing the same steps in reverse.
> - Allows the scripts to execute in some sequential manner.

It is also possible to execute raw SQL `ALTER TABLE` statements.

See [**How to execute raw SQL in Flask-SQLAlchemy app**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17972020/1164465)

Answer (score 3):

Using Flask Migrate :

1- you need to add manage.py that will handle the migration.

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from app import app, db


migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

2 - Run the following after you make a change in models.py

```
- python manage.py db init #creates the migration folder (one time only)
- python manage.py db migrate

#Choose one of both options : 
- python manage.py db upgrade # update the db automatically
- python manage.py db upgrade --sql > migration.sql # update the "migration.sql" file with the updated sql script.
```

In the development mode, usually you need to run these two commands one by one after you make a new change on the model :

```
python manage.py db migrate
python manage.py db upgrade
```

In case of this error when migrating: " Target database is not up to date."

```
python manage.py db stamp head
python manage.py db migrate
python manage.py db upgrade
```

STEPS TO FIX ERRORS WITH MIGRATIONS FOLDER: this could happen if you updated the db manually for some reason or some other kind of problems.

```
drop table alembic_version  #sql command to run in front of the db ) 
delete migrations folder    #manually from the project tree
python manage.py db init
python manage.py db migrate
python manage.py db upgrade
```