# How to execute a stored procedure in sqlalchemy , sqllite in memory?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I need to create a stored procedure in memory for my unit test. I'm using python/sqlalchemy/sqlite for the unit tests. I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'executeSql'

Is there a better way to create the stored procedure using session?

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
class TestEscalation(unittest.TestCase):

     def setUp(self):
            app.config.from_object('config.Testing')
            self.app = app.test_client()
            with app.app_context():
                db.session.close()
                db.drop_all()
                db.create_all()
                db.session.add(lobalarmescalationtime(id=1, clientid ='AS0001',priorityid = 1,escalationtime = 120))
                db.executeSql('./dbscripts/storedproc.sql')
                db.session.commit()
            app.app_context().push()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out like;
           `db.session.execute(open("./resources/storedproc.sql").read()`)

Answer (score 0):

just google these keywords: sqlalchemy execute sql

there are so many answer:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
```

with engine.connect() as con:

```
data = ( { "id": 1, "title": "The Hobbit", "primary_author": "Tolkien" },
         { "id": 2, "title": "The Silmarillion", "primary_author": "Tolkien" },
)

statement = text("""INSERT INTO book(id, title, primary_author) VALUES(:id, :title, :primary_author)""")

for line in data:
    con.execute(statement, **line)
```

or

```
with engine.connect() as con:

rs = con.execute('SELECT * FROM book')

for row in rs:
    print row
```

and you can view this page on stack overflow with had answered by other guys:

[How to execute raw SQL in Flask-SQLAlchemy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-flask-sqlalchemy-app)

enjoy