# How to create tables and perform queries in Flask without using models?

Tags: python, sql, flask, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a table in Amazon Redshift with Flask, since you can't use models to create tables, how can I create them with SQL directly?

for example .execute ("CREATE TABLE ..."

Comment: Have you looked at this redshift-sqlalchemy plugin? https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift. For creating tables you probably want to consider Alembic: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute raw SQL queries in a Flask app, [use SQLAlchemy's `execute()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-flask-sqlalchemy-app)

```py
result = db.engine.execute("<sql here>")
```

I would question your assumptions that you cannot use models (presumably from sql-alchemy) to create tables. I am not a Redshift user, but it seems that once the SQL connection is there, [most standard SQL features would be available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-sql.html), and you can use tools like [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/index.html) and [Alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) to work with models instead of raw SQL. It appears there is already a [SQLAlchemy plugin to help with Redshift connections](https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift).