# Python Flask update table

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my first model:

```
class Userauth(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'userauth'    

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
```

After I made my table in my database, then I'm trying to sign up or create a new user but I got this error:

```
"Something went wrong: (psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation) value too long for type character varying(50)"
```

I realize that I encode the password so it exceeds 50 characters, so I change my code from

```
password = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
```

to

```
password = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable = False)
```

But I still got the same error. When I check my database, my table didn't change the char value from 50 to 150. I have migrated and upgrade my database with `python manage.py db migrate` and `upgrade`, and there is no error for that but why my table didn't change? Is there any easy way to change or update our table in Flask? (I work with flask-sqlalchemy also), thank you.

Comment: Apparently you are using a migrate command that works for django but you are using flask, should check first how to migrate in flask

Comment: I have use `Migrate, MigrateCommand` from `flask_migrate` in my manage.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to run SQL command directly. Command would be for postgresql something like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Userauth ALTER COLUMN password TYPE varchar(150);
```

You can run SQL queries with Flask-SqlAlchemy db.session.execute -method. Further information about that: [How to execute raw SQL in Flask-SQLAlchemy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-flask-sqlalchemy-app)

Or it would be even easier if you can access your database console. This is one-time operation, so no need to include it into your applications code.