# Create a database trigger in an event listener

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask API and I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy to handle a SQLite database. I have a table which stores log entries, and I want to limit the maximum number of rows to a number n. Since insertions are also made from another script outside of flask using raw SQL, I created a trigger that checks the number of rows and deletes the oldest ones if the number is higher than n:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'trigger_log_insert' 
BEFORE INSERT ON 'connection_logs' 
WHEN ( SELECT count(*) FROM  'connection_logs' ) > 5 
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM 'connection_logs' 
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM 'connection_logs' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 ); 
END
```

This trigger works as expected, but I am struggling to set it using flask-sqlalchemy. How can I set the trigger / execute raw SQL using flask-sqlalchemy? The SQL only needs to be executed once after db creation so I intent to execute it right after my create_all() statement.
I stumbled upon [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-flask-sqlalchemy-app) which suggested a solution that is apparently going to be deprecated soon. I also read the [SQLAlchemy documentation about custom DDL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/ddl.html), but I don't know how to create this custom DDL with flask_sqlalchemy. When I create the DDL like in the SQLAlchemy documentation, I get an error message saying
`DDL object is not bound to an Engine or Connection.`:

```
trigger = DDL(
"CREATE TRIGGER 'trigger_log_insert'"
"BEFORE INSERT ON 'connection_logs'"
"WHEN ( SELECT count(*) FROM  'connection_logs' ) > 5"
"BEGIN"
"DELETE FROM 'connection_logs' WHERE id NOT IN"
"("
"SELECT id FROM 'connection_logs' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"
");"
"END"
)

event.listen(ConnectionLog, 'after_create', trigger.execute())
```

My model is defined using flask-sqlalchemy's declarative base model:

```
class ConnectionLog(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'connection_logs'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create a `DDL` instance, you can execute the SQL within the listener function.  The relevant docs are [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents).

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...

class ConnectionLog(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'connection_logs'
...

def after_create(target, connection, **kw):
    connection.execute(sa.text("""\
        CREATE TRIGGER 'trigger_log_insert'
        BEFORE INSERT ON 'connection_logs'
        WHEN ( SELECT count(*) FROM  'connection_logs' ) > 5
        BEGIN
        DELETE FROM 'connection_logs' WHERE id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT id FROM 'connection_logs' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
        );
        END
        """
    ))

# Listen on the underlying table object, not on the model class.
sa.event.listen(ConnectionLog.__table__, "after_create", after_create)
```

Ensure that the interpreter has read this code before creating the tables.

Comment: Works like a charm and in addition I also learned something about ORM events, thank you!