# Introduce LIMIT and OFFSET in any SQL query for any DBMS

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

### Context

I am looking for a way to programmatically introduce `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in **any SQL query** (provided in a conf file). To pad the initial query with `f"{query} LIMIT {params.offset} OFFSET {batch * params.offset}` typically works for simple SQL queries...

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 3400000
```

... but is **incorrect** for JOIN based queries (and probably many other cases)

```sql
SELECT d.DiagnosticIDUnique, d.LogementID, d.DateValidite, TypeEnergieLibelle_list, td.TypeDiagnostic, c.NomClient, c.SiretClient 
FROM DIAGNOSTIC as d LEFT JOIN TYPE_DIAGNOSTIC as td ON d.TypeDiagnosticID = td.TypeDiagnosticID  
LIMIT 100000 OFFSET 3400000
```

Moreover, `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` won't work for some DBMS such as MSSQL, which, from what I understood, relies on an `ORDER BY` and expects something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_table 
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 3400000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

### Need

Managing this complexity and providing an high level API is typically the job of an ORM. My project is based on pandas and comes with **SQLAlchemy** as a dependance. I wondered if I could

1. load a **query string** to create a `Query` object
2. easily introduce a pagination and
3. convert it back to a query string for the target DBMS

I am a complete noob on **SQLAlchemy** (only used Django's in previous projects). Here are some of the questions I am asking myself before digging into it

- Should I necessarily go through the creation of data models?
- Is this an overkill ? (some simpler, almost generic way to handle things)

Comment: OFFSET/FETCH FIRST is the ANSI/ISO SQL standard way. Probably most portable too.

Comment: ORDER BY always makes sense, at least if you don't mind a more or less random result.

Comment: @jarlh it's the standard, but not [universally supported](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html?highlight=fetch#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.fetch).

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I know, that's why I wrote _Probably most portable_. Is there any more common alternative?

Comment: I don't think so (apart from LIMIT/OFFSET of course), the OP may need to check the RDBMS to select the code to write.  Or perhaps some compiler magic in SQLA

Comment: Exactly @snakecharmerb . But since a query object in SQLA seems related with a specific connection, I wondered if it could

Comment: "incorrect for JOIN based queries" not sure why you think that, it's perfectly valid. To try doing this on multiple DBMSs is overkill. Just use your ORM. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-flask-sqlalchemy-app

Comment: Not all databases support `OFFSET`. Case in point Sybase. And I kind of agree with its decision.