# AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'execute' when trying to run sqlalchemy in python to manage my SQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following line of code that keeps giving me an error that Engine object has no object execute. I think I have everything right but no idea what keeps happening. It seemed others had this issue and restarting their notebooks worked. I'm using Pycharm and have restarted that without any resolution. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql


masterlist = pd.read_excel('Masterlist.xlsx')

user = 'root'
pw = 'test!*'
db = 'hcftest'

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost:3306/{db}"
                           .format(user=user, pw=pw, db=db))


results = engine.execute(text("SELECT * FROM companyname;"))

for row in results:
    print(row)
```

Comment: You need `engine.connect()`. It's lazy and won't actually connect until needed

Comment: `with engine.connect() as conn:`

Comment: Side note if you want a pretty good Python-based GUI driven MySQL Editor, 
Oracle created one that is FREE called MySQL Workbench, and it makes db work as easy as playing with Excel.  Unless you are just doing a proof in concept, you might want to look into it and save youself a ton of time.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There was a change from 1.4 to 2.0. The above code will run fine with sqlalchemy version 1.4 I believe. setting `SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 python` and running the above code reveals this warning:

```
<stdin>:1: RemovedIn20Warning: The Engine.execute() method is considered legacy as of the 1.x series of SQLAlchemy and will be removed in 2.0. All statement execution in SQLAlchemy 2.0 is performed by the Connection.execute() method of Connection, or in the ORM by the Session.execute() method of Session. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
```

So the correct way to do the code now is:

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt)
```

source [here describing the behavior in 1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#dbengine-implicit) and [here describing the behavior in 2.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-20-implicit-execution)

Comment: Did they make it harder to query dynamically on purpose?

Comment: One silver lining is that the `with ... as conn` new code works with 1.x and 2.x so you don't have to update everything everywhere causing a cascade avalanche of code-breaking updates, at least not yet.

Answer (score 8):

```
sql = f"""INSERT INTO user_apis
  (api_id, user_id, monthly_requests, total_requests)
  VALUES (1, {current_user.id}, 0, 0)"""
```

1.x

```
result = db.engine.execute(sql)
```

2.x

```
from sqlalchemy import text
with db.engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text(sql)) 
    conn.commit()              #2.x execute now only works with SELECT.
                               #Inserts, Updates and Deletes now must be 
                               #in a transaction and explicitly committed
                               #use engine echo=True to show transaction status
```

SELECT sql

```
with db.engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text(sql)).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from .. import db

def get():

    sql_statement = \
        """
            SELECT *
        """

    with db.engine.begin() as conn:
        response = conn.exec_driver_sql(sql_statement).all()
    
    return response
```