# Conditional Oracle INSERT ALL Statement with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

colleagues!

There is one question that I can't find an answer to:

Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy 1.4 to insert into several tables by conditions, while making a single select query? Interested in this query syntax (ORACLE):

```
INSERT [ ALL | FIRST ]
    WHEN condition1 THEN
        INTO table_1 (column_list ) VALUES (value_list)
    WHEN condition2 THEN 
        INTO table_2(column_list ) VALUES (value_list)
    ELSE
        INTO table_3(column_list ) VALUES (value_list)
Subquery
```

At the moment, all I have come up with is to execute a subquery and iterate on its results using `if..elif..`.

But this method obviously loses to the above query both in speed and in memory consumption.

If anyone has any ideas on this issue, please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, if you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (id NUMBER, a NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE table_2 (id NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE table_3 (id NUMBER, a NUMBER, c NUMBER);
```

Then you can use the query:

```sql
INSERT ALL
  WHEN a < 5 THEN
    INTO table_1 (id, a) VALUES (id, a)
  WHEN a >= 3 AND a < 7 THEN
    INTO table_2 (id, b, c) VALUES (id, b, c)
  WHEN a >= 4 AND a < 8 THEN
    INTO table_3 (id, a, c) VALUES (id, a, c)
SELECT 1 As id, 1 AS a, 1 AS b, 1 AS c FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5, 5, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 6, 6, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 7, 7, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 8, 8, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the tables contain:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_1
```

| ID | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_2
```

| ID | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 |

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_3
```

| ID | A | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 | 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IZAjueVI)

---

> Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy 1.4 to insert into several tables by conditions, while making a single <s>select</s> `INSERT` query?

Yes, just directly execute the SQL. See [How to execute raw SQL in Flask-SQLAlchemy app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17987782/1509264), which will work for user-defined `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements.

```python
your_sql = """INSERT ALL
  WHEN a < 5 THEN
    INTO table_1 (id, a) VALUES (id, a)
  WHEN a >= 3 AND a < 7 THEN
    INTO table_2 (id, b, c) VALUES (id, b, c)
  WHEN a >= 4 AND a < 8 THEN
    INTO table_3 (id, a, c) VALUES (id, a, c)
SELECT 1 As id, 1 AS a, 1 AS b, 1 AS c FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5, 5, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 6, 6, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 7, 7, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 8, 8, 8 FROM DUAL"""

db.engine.execute(text(your_sql)).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

Comment: I may not have asked the question correctly, but I knew about the execution of raw sql. I would like to know if this can be implemented using sqlalchemy core/orm tools?